# How to introduce into optimization algorithm a linear constraint which involves calculated variables which depend on decision variables

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints

An optimization problem consists of an objective function which should be minimized, 10 decision variables (from `x(1)` to `x(10)`) and some constraints.

In the objective function some additional variables are calculated, i.e.

```
Variable1=5*x(5)+x(1)*10-25
Variable2=x(1)=5*x(2)+50*x(10)
```

etc.

The problem is that I want to put both above calculated variables (`Variable1` and `Variable2`) which are functions of decision variables into the constraints function. For example:

```
Variable1>=100
Variable2<50
```

To do this I am trying to put these conditions into the constraint function:

```
function [c,ceq] = constraints(x)
c = [-Variable1+100;
Variable2-50;];

ceq = [];
```

I know that these constraints are linear, but it is impossible to put them as linear constraints =>`A*X<b`, because linear constraints can contain only decision variables.

In this form the `fmincon` algorithm does not take into account the above conditions. How can I add these constraints anyway?

Comment: What prevents you from putting `Variable1=5*x(5)+x(1)*10-25` and `Variable2=x(1)=5*x(2)+50*x(10)` inside the `constraints.m` function? Apart from this, looks like you could write Variable1 and Variable2 as some `A*x` where `A=[1,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0;1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50]`.

Comment: If your two variables can be expressed in function of `x`, you can simply write the full expression, no ? something like: `c = [-(5*x(5)+x(1)*10-25) + 100;...`

Comment: Unfortunately this is impossible. The problem, which I am supposed to solve consists of 5000 decision variables and takes into account many thermodynamical relationships. It is impossible to express all these variables as functions of decision variables...

Answer (score 1):

```
Variable1 = 5*x(5) + x(1)*10 -25
```

Write `Variable1` including all the decision variables, the missing ones have `0` as coefficient

```
Variable1 = 10*x(1) + 0*x(2) + 0*x(3) + 0*x(4) + 5*x(5) + ...
            0*x(6) + 0*x(7) + 0*x(8) + 0*x(9) + 0*x(10) -25

Variable1 >=100

10*x(1) + 0*x(2) + 0*x(3) + 0*x(4) + 5*x(5) + ...
0*x(6) + 0*x(7) + 0*x(8) + 0*x(9) + 0*x(10) -25 >= 100
```

left hand side should contain only decision variables
remove `-25` from left side by adding `+25` to both sides

```
10*x(1) + 0*x(2) + 0*x(3) + 0*x(4) + 5*x(5) + ...
0*x(6) + 0*x(7) + 0*x(8) + 0*x(9) + 0*x(10)  >= 100 + 25
```

change `>=` to `<=` by multiplying both sides by `-1`

```
-10*x(1) - 0*x(2) - 0*x(3) - 0*x(4) - 5*x(5) - ...
0*x(6) - 0*x(7) - 0*x(8) - 0*x(9) - 0*x(10)  <= -100 - 25
```

- `A` first row: copy left hand side decision variable coefficients

```
A(1, :) = [-10, -0, -0, -0, -5, -0, -0, -0, -0, -0]
```

- `b` first row: copy right hand side value

```
b(1, :) = -100-25;
```

---

> Same logic for `Variable2`

```
Variable2 = x(1) + 5*x(2)+50*x(10)
Variable2 = x(1) + 5*x(2) + 0*x(3) + 0*x(4) + 0*x(5) + ...
            0*x(6) + 0*x(7) + 0*x(8) + 0*x(9) + 50*x(10)

Variable2 < 50

1*x(1) + 5*x(2) + 0*x(3) + 0*x(4) + 0*x(5) + ...
0*x(6) + 0*x(7) + 0*x(8) + 0*x(9) + 50*x(10) < 50
```

- `A` second row

```
A(2, :) = [+1, +5, +0, +0, +0, +0, +0, +0, +0, +50]
```

- `b` second row

```
b(2, :) = +50
```

---

Overall `A` and `b`

```
A = [-10, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     1, 5, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 50 ]
```

```
b = [-125; 50]
```

Comment: Thank for replies. However this is not so simple :) The problem, which I am supposed to solve consists of over 5000 decision variables and takes into account many thermodynamical relationships. It is impossible to express all these variables as functions of decision variables... I need to put these variables into constraints function. I searched many help matlab websites but there only simple cases are considered.

Comment: Shows us few of those constraints or something similar